# Why is python calculating this way?

Tags: python, rounding-error

I tried to print a values from a 2-dimensions-array in python's numpy:

```
print(y[-1,-1], 1-y[-1,-1], -y[-1,-1], 1+y[-1,-1])
```

and here is what I got printed:

```
0.498714091773 0.501285908227 -0.498714091773 1.49871409177
```

Why is the value of `y[-1,-1]` 0.498714091773 and the one of `1-y[-1,-1]` 0.501285908227? If we take the limits of the ability of my computer in consideration, wouldn't `1-y[-1,-1]` be something like 0.49**9** and something?

Here is how I define my code and where y[] comes from:

```
def mouse(t, y):
    dy = np.array([1-(y[0]+y[1]), y[0]-y[1]])
    return dy

def euler(f, x, y, h):
    yn = y + h*f(x,y)
    xn = x + h
    return xn, yn

def integrate(method, f, t0, y0, tend, h):
    T = [t0]
    Y = [y0]
    t = t0
    y = y0
    while t < tend:
        h = min(h, tend-t)
        t, y = method(f, t, y, h)
        T.append(t)
        Y.append(y)
    return np.array(T), np.array(Y)

t, y = integrate(euler, mouse, 0, [0,0], 6, 0.05)
print(y[-1,-1], 1-y[-1,-1], -y[-1,-1], 1+y[-1,-1])
```

Comment: Why would it be .499 and something? Your computer did the subtraction correctly.

Comment: -y[-1,-1] is -0.498714091773. So if you add 1 to it, wouldn't it be 1.498714091773 ? Okay, there is rounding, cause there are still few digits missing from the orginial y[-1,-1], but I still don't really get it

Comment: @ZelelB No, it wouldn't. Use your calculator, if necessary, to convince yourself of this.

Comment: oh god! You're right! I definitely need to go get some rest! Lol! Thanks and sorry for the bothering!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't chase through your code to see where $y[-1,-1]$ comes from.  It looks like it is a numerical integration that might have an analytic value of $\frac 12$.  Given the value for $y[-1,-1]$ the other values are exactly what you would expect.  If you add $y[-1,-1]$ to $1-y[-1,-1]$ you get $1$ very nicely.  Why should $1-y[-1,-1]$ be $0.499$  You are doing exactly the same computation of $y[-1,-1]$ each time, so it should return the same value, then you are negating it, subtracting from $1$, and adding to $1$

Comment: shouldn't it be 0.498714091773? Or the negation eliminates few bits to save before adding the 1? Or I need to stop learning and go get some sleep after 12h sitting here

Comment: No, $1-0.4987=0.5013$  I still don't see why you think subtracting $0.4987$ from $1$ should give some other value.  Yes, the last few digits might be off, but they are not here.

Comment: I am seeing it the whole time from the other perspective: −0.4987 + 1! so it would be 1.4987 and the rest or at least 1.4990 and the rest.. why rounding on the 2nd digit after the comma

Comment: oh god! You're right! I definitely need to go get some rest! Lol! Thanks man